# escaping a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to insert the following as the value for a variable in some Ruby:

```
`~!@#$%^&*()_-+={}|[]\:";'<>?,./
```

Surrounding this in double quotes doesn't work, so is there a nice escape_until_the_end sort of thing available?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't use multiple methods - keep it simple.

Escape the #, the backslash, and the double-quote.

```
irb(main):001:0> foo = "`~!@\#$%^&*()_-+={}|[]\\:\";'<>?,./"
=> "`~!@\#$%^&*()_-+={}|[]\\:\";'<>?,./"
```

Or if you don't want to escape the # (the substitution character for variables in double-quoted strings), use and escape single quotes instead:

```
irb(main):002:0> foo = '`~!@#$%^&*()_-+={}|[]\\:";\'<>?,./'
=> "`~!@\#$%^&*()_-+={}|[]\\:\";'<>?,./"
```

%q is great for lots of other strings that don't contain every ascii punctuation character.  :)

```
%q(text without parens)
%q{text without braces}
%Q[text without brackets with #{foo} substitution]
```

Edit: Evidently you can used balanced parens inside %q() successfully as well, but I would think that's slightly dangerous from a maintenance standpoint, as there's no semantics there to imply that you're always going to necessarily balance your parens in a string.

Comment: Actually, `%q()` works fine even if the inner text has parentheses - as long as they inner parentheses are balanced: `bal = %q(foo(()))`

Comment: There is no need to escape *anything*. `%q{\`~!@#$%^&*()_-+={}|[]\:";'<>?,./}` works fine.

Answer (score 8):

First, unless I'm crazy `%q()` *does* work here, perfectly well, since the inner parentheses are balanced:

```
>> weird = %q(`~!@#$%^&*()_-+={}|[]\:";'<>?,./)
=> "`~!@\#$%^&*()_-+={}|[]\\:";'<>?,./"
>> puts weird
`~!@#$%^&*()_-+={}|[]\:";'<>?,./
```

As a side note: when using `%q`, you always have the nuclear option of using spaces as the delimiter. This is **foul** and officially a Bad Idea, but it works.

Again, I wouldn't do it, but just to see...

```
>> weird = %q `~!@#$%^&*()_-+={}|[]\:";'<>?,./ 
=> "`~!@\#$%^&*()_-+={}|[]\\:";'<>?,./"
```

Comment: +1 because you are right! Could have sworn that failed when I tested it!

Answer (score 2):

`<<EOT`, and `%q{}` are your friends. Info on using them from the [Programming Ruby
The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/tut_stdtypes.html#S2).

Try mixing the various approaches:

```
%q{`~!@#$%^&*()_-+}+"{}"+%q{=|[]\\:";'<>?,./}
```

or alternatively, just use backslashes to escape the problematic chars:

```
"`~!@\#$%^&*()_-+{}=|[]\\:\";'<>?,./"
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd normally think of would be a **%q** directive -- but since you seem to be using all the punctuation you'd normally use to delimit one, I can't think of an easy way to make it work here.

The second thing I'd think of would be a heredoc:

```
mystring = <<END
`~!@#$%^&*()_-+={}|[]\:";'<>?,./
END
```

That breaks after the backslash, though.

So my third answer, clunky but the best thing I can think of with just two minutes' thought, would be to substitute something harmless for the "problem" characters and then substitute it after the assignment:

```
mystring = '`~!@#$%^&*()_-+={}|[]\:"; <>?,./'.tr(" ","'")
```

I don't like it, but it works.

Comment: He can use `%q` here - even though he's using punctuation.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I didn't even think to try what you tried. Good going.