# JSON::ParserError (399: unexpected token at

Tags: ruby, json

when I'm going to parse this:

```
Product = [{"Productname":"Acer 18.5" LED Monitor}]
```

with Ruby JSOn, its showing me the error `JSON::ParserError (399: unexpected token at`. I know this is for 18.5" in the string. How can I parse this string?

Comment: Rather than fixing the parsing of the string, you need to encode it correctly in the first place.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634349/escaping-a-string-in-ruby

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the string like this

```
Product = [{"productname":%q{"Acer 18.5" LED Monitor}}]
```

Comment: But i'm getting this dynamically from other end how can i manipulate them.. its need to solve in my end by parsing. but how can i do that ?

Comment: you can parse only a valid json string format. so you have to change at where you created this.

Comment: it has been resolved by this REGX gsub(/"\s/, '\" ') only condition is that after double quotes there should be a "space"

Comment: OK if u can do like that give like this                               Product = [{"productname":"\"Acer 18.5\" LED Monitor"}]

Answer (score -1):

If you have an issue with `Mongoid` + `Devise` add this to your `User` model ([bug page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2949#issuecomment-53201813)):

```
def to_key
  id.to_s
end
```

Answer (score -1):

In your /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb lines 5 and 6, change the first parameter from application to default.

I met the same problem, too for my situation, after changing it the problem was resolved happens on Windows. The parameter application works on the web server.